# Dependency injection ASP.Net Core in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.0 project with a lot of dependency injection.

I'm working also on a WPF app (.NET Framework 4.8), and I would like to use a service implemented in the ASP.NET project.
Is it possible t do that in a few lines of code ? And how can I use it ?
This service requires a lot of other service, and it will be long to instanciate each services one by one.

Thanks !

Comment: Your WPF app doesn't need to know anything about the asp.net project's dependencies. Are you trying to share the same model classes or something?

Comment: As long as your service and its dependencies comply with the .NET Standard 2.0 or below, you can share them with a .NET Framework project using version 4.6.1 and above. Generally, .NET Core specific libraries are not supported by .NET Framework. This means your libraries should be compiled with .NET Standard, in order to be able to share them between .NET Core and .NET Framework applications or projects. If you can't convert the projects because of incompatible dependencies, you can provide alternative implementations and use multi-targeting.

Comment: To resolve the dependencies, once you want to instantiate the required service, I recommend [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/). MEF is very straight forward, lightweight and doesn't require complicated or lines of code intensive configuration. [Getting started with convention-based part registration in MEF 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2011/11/01/getting-started-with-convention-based-part-registration-in-mef-2-nick/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a new service collection in which you then register your services. You can then build the collection to a service provider and use that resolve your service and have it automatically provide the dependent services:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();

// add your services
services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
services.AddTransient<Dependency1>();
services.AddTransient<Dependency2>();

// build service provider
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

// resolve the service from the service provider
var service = serviceProvider.GetService<MyService>();
```

Ideally, you would do the setup of the service provider only *once* at some very early and central location in your app. For example, WPF’s `App.xaml.cs` or something and store it statically so other components can access the service provider to resolve this and other services.

For registering your services and its dependencies, you can also follow the common pattern of creating reusable extension methods that register a set of related services. For example, you could do this and then use that method in both ASP.NET Core and your WPF application:

```
public IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<MyService>();
    services.AddTransient<Dependency1>();
    services.AddTransient<Dependency2>();

    return services;
}
```

You can then just call `services.AddMyServices()` to add all these services to your service collection.

That being said, using dependency injection in WPF is actually something that has been covered by a number of frameworks already. These will usually not use the dependency injection container from ASP.NET Core (simply because those framework usually predate ASP.NET Core) but have similar ones with similar features. These WPF frameworks also often come with a good setup for [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) and a lot of specific WPF-related helpers. Example frameworks (without any recommendation from my side) would be [Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/), [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/), or [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/index.html).